# Passing pointers to string arrays to toupper() in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to pass a pointer array of strings to function toupper() in C.

```
main() {
    char *choice[1];
    scanf("%s", choice);
    printf("%s", toupper(&choice[0]));
}
```

I always type in a lowercase word such as "modify" to test it.  Different variations of this, such as `toupper(*choice[0])` or `toupper(*choice)` or mixtures of them all, including `&`, have either thrown an error or returned the same lowercase "modify".  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're not passing the right type to `scanf` in both cases. It expects a `char *`.

Comment: Change also the %s to %c

Comment: The `toupper` function doesn't take an array of strings, so why would you try to pass it one?

Comment: `choice` is an array of pointers, not chars (one element long, so not much of an array, but still). Second, `scanf()` is expecting a `char*` you're giving it a `char**`. Next, `toupper` is expecting an `int` and you're giving it a `char**`. Lastly, your main (which is implicitly an `int` returning function as you have defined it), has no return value. In summary. *every* line of code in this snippet is wrong except the array decl, and thats right only if you want an array of pointers (which you actually don't).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Also, `toupper` returns an `int` but is passed for the `%s` specifier, which expects a string.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And the hits just keep on coming...

Comment: If you scanf into a 1-character buffer your application isn't going to live very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with array of `char` pointers having one element doesn't make much sense to me since it will only point to one string.Why not declare a `char` array if you just want a single string?

Prototype of `toupper` is this:

```
int toupper( int ch );
```

It doesn't take an array.

You can try like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{

  char str[25];
  int i = 0;

  setbuf(stdout,NULL);

  printf ("enter the name \n");
  fgets (str,sizeof str-1, stdin);


  printf ("the name entered in upper case is :\n");
  while (str[i])
    {
      int c = str[i];
      printf ("%c",toupper(c));
      i++;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE-** Do not use `scanf` for taking strings try `fgets` , its better.

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert at C and don't exactly know how long the input is going to be.  I figured it'd save space, too.  As I said, I'm still quite a beginner.

Comment: @kizlink If you don't wanna hard code the array then either `char str[]="some string";` will be good OR you can also define VLA which you should take care while defining that these are legal from C99 only .... not in previous standards .... dynamically allocating memory e.g using `malloc` can also do wonders :) ....... If you are a beginner I think you should try out things rather bothering about spaces and speed .... do mistakes ;they are important , that's the way you learn ... no one is born perfect

Comment: Yeah, I've read a little about but haven't touched memory allocation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `scanf`, you need to allocate some space for the characters to be stored in. You only allocate a single pointer and then you don't even set it to point to anything. Similarly, `toupper` returns the converted character, which is not a string, so passing it to `printf` through `%s` is also wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should serve the purpose.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void StrToUpper(char *str)
{
  while(*str != '\0')
  {
    *str = toupper(*str);
    str++;
  }
}
int main()
{
  char *choice[1];
  choice[1] =  new char[10];
  scanf("%s", choice[1]);
  StrToUpper(choice[1]);
  printf("%s", choice[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new char[10]` is illegal in C

Comment: Why not just declare the string `char choice[10];` if you're going to scan a string?

Comment: The answer posted is just to show what was wrong witht he code, the desired output can be achieved in other ways as well. no doubt. in c, you can use malloc and           @busy_wait: yes , you can declare choice[10] and it would be cleaner code.

Answer (score -1):

In the program, you have array of pointers.

So:

1. Allocate memory for your string
2. call `toupper(choice[0][0]);`

`toupper` takes only a character value (between 0 and 255), not a pointer or array.